# Error on form load because of combo box selected Index

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to populate the text box according to the item selected in the combo box. The problem is it throws the following error on load and it I press next..next in visual studio.. it does what I actually want to do.

[image]
How can I solve the problem on load.

Code for Form load is

```
private void UpdateProduct_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet ds = GetAllItems();
            comboBox2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Product Name";
            comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0;


        }
```

Code for selected index for combo box is

```
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // string selectedText = this.comboBox2.GetItemText(this.comboBox2.SelectedItem);
            DataSet d = GetProductInfo(comboBox2.Text);
            if (d.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                textBox2.Text = d.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Quantity"].ToString();
                textBox3.Text = d.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Color"].ToString();
                textBox4.Text = d.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Size"].ToString();
                textBox5.Text = d.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Price"].ToString();
            }

        }
```

I have only problem when the form loads for first time.

GetProductInfo Code

```
  public DataSet GetProductInfo(string product)
        {
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            OleDbConnection oleConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);

            try
            {
                oleConn.Open();
                string sql = "SELECT [Quantity], [Color], [Size], [Price] FROM [Product] WHERE [Product Name]= '" + product + "'";
                OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, oleConn);
                dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "Product");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An exception has been occured\n" + ex.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                oleConn.Close();
            }
            if (dataSet.Tables["Product"].Rows.Count <= 0)
                return null;

            return dataSet;
        }
```

Stack Trace

```
System.NullReferenceException occurred
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=Purchase Management
  StackTrace:
       at Purchase_Management.UpdateProduct.comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Amrit\Desktop\Purchase Management\Purchase Management\UpdateProduct.cs:line 99
  InnerException:
```

Comment: can you show the code for `GetProductInfo()`?

Comment: please replicate the error again (in Visual Studio, in debug mode) and when you see the Exception description popup, click the link "Copy exception detail to the clipboard". After an intermediate step (using Notepad or something) in which you sanitize the details so that no one will know any secrets your company doesn't allow you to tell, please send us the StackTrace (partially censored if needed) section from those details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using SelectedIndexChanged, use the **SelectionChangeCommitted** event.  This avoids all those problems as it only fires when the *user* changes the selected item rather than when you are initializing the combobox.

Comment: How can i activate that SelectionChangeCommitted

Answer (score 0):

your method returning null.  that's why error thrown

```
DataSet dstProduct = new DataSet();
dstProduct = GetProductInfo(comboBox2.Text);
```

then  try

```
if(dstProduct.Tables.Count>0 && dstProduct.Tables[0].Rows.Count >0)
{
 // then do stuff. 
}
```

Comment: should it be the case that `GetProductInfo` returns `null` then any previous assignments to the variable `dstProduct` are irrelevant since the final assignment will overwrite any initially non-null reference that was stored in `dstProduct` with `null`

Answer (score 0):

Because `.Count` fires an exeption in case of `d = null`.

Declare `DataSet d = new DataSet();`

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(productName))` statement and you'll be alright:

```
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var productName = comboBox2.Text;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(productName)) {

        DataSet d = GetProductInfo(productName);
        if (d.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            textBox2.Text = d.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Quantity"].ToString();
            textBox3.Text = d.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Color"].ToString();
            textBox4.Text = d.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Size"].ToString();
            textBox5.Text = d.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Price"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```